# How to get Canon 1200D quantum efficency plot?

Tags: canon, astrophotography, physics, science

I've searched quantum efficency of Canon 1200D and I found some images like here: http://www.deep-sky.co.uk/imaging/dslr/dslr.htm .
How these people get quantum efficency plots for mentioned Canon 40D? Do you ask some Canon's R&D department or they measured it by themselfs?
If former do anyone can know where to call or send e-mail at Canon to get those plots?

Answer (score 1):

Canon is not in the habit of releasing such information. The source of the data reflected in the chart at your link was measured by someone else. If you notice, in the lower right corner is the following text:

> Canon data © Christian Bull

There are a few [well known sources](http://www.clarkvision.com/articles/digital.sensor.performance.summary/) for independent measurements of camera sensor quantum efficiency. But most of them concentrate on the higher end cameras.

Comment: I've suspected that we were encroaching theoretical limits on sensor efficiency, but never seen a study that validates it. Thanks for the link!

Comment: Approaching it, maybe. Encroaching it, probably never.

Comment: Hah! My sloppy language strikes again; good catch.